# How can I load my mustache template with PHP?

Tags: mustache.php

index.php:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

require('v/Mustache/Autoloader.php');

Mustache_Autoloader::register();

$m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
    'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader(dirname(__FILE__) . '/v'),
));

// loads template from `v/sign_in.mustache` and renders it.
$m->render('sign_in', array('planet' => 'world'));

?>
```

v/sign_in.mustache:

```
<h1>Where in the {{planet}} is Carmen San Diego?</h1>
```

When I load index.php, I see a big blank screen with no errors.

Comment: you need to echo $m->render() i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $m->render('sign_in', array('planet' => 'world'));
```